# BIRT report how to decrypt password from db and show

Tags: java, oracle, birt

is there any possibility to show decrypted the encrypted password field or any other encrypted field from oracle database and display in BIRT report?

Comment: I presume that - if you know how to *decrypt* it - then yes. Otherwise, I suppose not.

Comment: What password are we talking about? Oracle user passwords, or application-encrypted data?

Answer (score 1):

If you're talking about Oracle user account passwords, then the answer is "no". Oracle does not store the encrypted password anywhere in the database, only the one-way hash, which cannot be decrypted.

- https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/DBSEG/authentication.htm#DBSEG30341 "Oracle Database generates a one-way hash of the user's password and stores it for use when verifying the provided login password."
- https://seanstuber.com/how-oracle-stores-passwords/

If you're talking about application-encrypted data, then it would depend on *how* the data was encrypted.

- If it was encrypted within the database, using a package like
  DBMS_CRYPTO, and the report has access to the encryption keys and the
  ability to execute the decryption function as part of the query, then
  "yes".
- If it was encrypted externally from the database by an application
  and simply stored as encrypted data, then "probably not", as you would
  not have access within the database to the encryption keys  or
  algorithms required.
- If the data is encrypted at rest with Oracle's Transparent Data Encryption, then there is no need to do anything. Oracle will decrypt the data automatically as it is selected and stored in memory.

Answer (score 0):

IF you mean the DB password that is stored in the properties of a DataSource in a *.rptdesign or *.rptlibrary file:
This is only base64-encrypted (slightly better than clear text). So decrypting it is easy.

Comment: Hi hvb, thanks for prompt reply. I have a field value in db with base64 encryption (not password fields.. just some other field), how to decrypt in expression builder? is there any example?

Comment: That's a different topic.